# Problema com a ordem de execução de endpoints no Express com caminhos conflituosos

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express.js

Estou com essa dúvida relativa aos *endpoints* criados em Express.

Neste primeiro trecho, o *endpoint* `/anuncios/:search` deve pesquisar nos campos `descricao` e `nome` pelo texto informado. Portanto, uma chamada `/anuncios/carro` vai retornar todos os resultados com `carro` no nome ou descrição.

```
app.get('/anuncios/:search', function (req, res) {
    let search = req.params.search;
  
    if (!search) {
        return res.status(400).send({message: 'Nada encontrado para ' +search });
    }
    else
    {  
        search = '%' +search.replace(' ', '%') +'%';

        dbConn.query(
            'SELECT * FROM anuncios where (descricao LIKE ?) '
            +'OR (nome LIKE ?)', 
                [search, search], function(err, result){
                res.send(result)
        });
    }  
});
```

Já neste segundo *endpoint*, ele deve busca o ID informado. Desta forma, ao dar um `GET /anuncios/id/2`, a API retorna o anuncio de ID 2.

```
app.get('/anuncios/id/:id', function (req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
  
    if (!id) {
        return res.status(400).send({message: 'Nenhum ID informado'});
    }
    else
    {  
        dbConn.query(
            'SELECT * FROM anuncios where id = ?', [id], 
            function(err, result){
                res.send(result)                
            }
        );
    }  
});
```

Meu problema é quando eu faço uma chamada com ID vazio (`GET /anuncios/id/`). Nesse caso, a API está fazendo uma consulta no primeiro *endpoint*, buscando nomes e descrições com o ID informado no texto.

Como eu devo fazer para montar essa chamada sem esse problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso não é um bug. Está funcionando como o código "mandou". Lembre-se que código nada mais é do que uma série de instruções a um computador.

A questão é que o Express executa os *handlers* de cada rota de acordo com a ordem a qual foram definidos. Desse modo, o *handler* que vier primeiro no código será executado primeiro. [Consulte a documentação de roteamento do Express para saber mais.](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Quando você coloca o *handler* de `/anuncios/:search`, o Express terá o "registrado" primeiro. Assim, quando você pede ao servidor por `/anuncios/id/` ("ID vazio"), ele vai achar que o ID é um termo válido para pesquisa.

Para contornar isso, basta inverter a ordem dos *handlers*, de modo a também tornar a presença do parâmetro ID opcional (para isso utilizamos o sinal de interrogação):

```js
//           Campo ID é agora opcional
//                       ↓
app.get('/anuncios/id/:id?', function (req, res) {
  const id = req.params.id;

  // Não esqueça de tratar o caso do ID não ter sido informado:
  if (!id) {
    res.status(400).send('Erro. Você deve informar um ID.');
    return;
  }

  res.send(`Procurado pelo ID: "${id}".`);
});

app.get('/anuncios/:search', function (req, res) {
  const search = req.params.search;

  res.send(`Procurado pelo termo: "${search}".`);
});
```

O único problema dessa abordagem é que agora você não poderá procurar por entidades a partir do termo ID, já que ele é "reservado".

Para contornar esse (possível) problema, você pode também criar dois *endpoints* um pouco mais distintos. Algo como:

- `/anuncios/id/:id`, que faria a busca pelo ID.
- `/anucios/termo/:termo`, que faria a busca por algum termo de pesquisa.

Comment: Valeu, Luiz! Ficou bem clara a ideia agora!